# How do I properly update an item in my array in redux without mutating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
const state = [
    {
        list: []
    }
];
```

The list is a list of student objects, for example:

```
list: [
   { id: 1, name: "Mark", attendance: true },
   { id: 2, name: "John", attendance: false }
]
```

I have a button that triggers a post request to an API to change attendance to true. Post request returns the student object that was changed as in e.g.:

```
{ id: 2, name: "John", attendance: true }
```

This works fine and if no errors, will dispatch `ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS`.

Now, with this kind of set-up:

```
export function students(state, action) {
    let latestState = state[state.length - 1],
        newState = Object.assign({}, latestState);
    switch (action.type) {
       case "ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS":
          if (action.res.errorCode == 0) {
             // Need to change redux state 'attendance' value to true for a student with ID returned from the POST request
          }
    }
```

Initially, I did:

```
const studentChanged = newState.list.find(function(student) {
  return (
        student.id ===
        action.res.data.id
  );
});
studentChanged.attendance = true;
```

But it mutates the state in the redux store (although I am not sure how it's exactly happening since I assumed newState is already a copy).

What's the proper way?

Comment: [Updating an Item in an Array](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/immutableupdatepatterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following would update a single item in the array. The critical aspect here is that if the `id` of the item does not match the `id` from the action payload, it returns the item unaltered, otherwise it updates the `attendance` property. `Array.prototype.map` returns a new array so it would be immutable.

```
export function students(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS":
      if (action.res.errorCode == 0) {
        return state.map(student => {
          // we want to leave non matching items unaltered
          if (student.id !== action.res.data.id) {
            return student;
          }

          return { ...student, attendance: true };
        });
      }

      return state;          
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6mru22) to demonstrate the functionality.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: What does { ...student, attendance: true } do? It's as if it's copying the entire student object but just changing attendance property to a different value?

Comment: Correct, It's the [Object Spread Operator](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingobjectspreadoperator). It's effectively `Object.assign()`, just more succinct. Copy all enumerable properties, then additional argument values, in this case the property `attendance`, get merged into that newly created object.